# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.162.26.95:17185

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I cant  get response from server.js. My server.js is here:

```
//dependencies

var express = require('express');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//connect to mongodb

mongoose.connect('mongodb://yourdbus:yourdbpw@ds017185.mlab.com:17185/myfbdb');

//express

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes

app.use('/api' , require('./routes/api'));

//start server

app.listen(1050);
console.log('server is running on port 1050');
```

Comment: Please put the `console.log('...')` inside a callback, as an argument to `app.listen`. Maybe the port is used already

Comment: problem with mongodb, even I can connect to mongodb via telnet ds017185.mlab.com:17185, but seems like mongodb's username or password or database name is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem with mongodb.

I can connect to mongodb via telnet ds017185.mlab.com:17185, but seems like mongodb's username, password or database name is not valid.

to check it replace mongoose.connect line with this, You'll get info about the problem:

```
var connectionString = 'mongodb://yourdbus:yourdbpw@ds017185.mlab.com:17185/myfbdb';
mongoose.connect(connectionString);

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error('Database connection error:', error);
});

mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Database connected');
});
```

In short: if You cannot fix problem, so check mongodb, reinstall it or etc. to make it work.

Comment: I had this error as you say  : 
Database connection error: { [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.162.26.95:17185]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 54.162.26.95:17185' }

Comment: sooo... seems like database does not exist. have You access to mongodb from terminal? check Your username and password if they are valid and have access to database.