# Mongoose deployment issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to Mongolab through the Expressjs. But when I run ,I am getting **failed to connect to the server**

Error Message :

```
    MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds033066.mlab.com:33066] on first con
nect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.80.215.206:33066]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rkishore\Documents\node\node_modules\mongoose\
node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:328:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rkishore\Documents\node\node_modules\mon
goose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rkishore\Documents\node\node_modules\mongoos
e\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:177:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [ds033066.mlab.com:33066] on first conne
ct [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.80.215.206:33066]'
```

Any Help/Suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332841/error-connect-etimedout-54-162-26-9517185

Comment: @H.Hakvoort. Thank you. But I already tried ad implemented that method. But still i got same error

Comment: You can `telnet ds033066.mlab.com 33066` to see if the desired server:port is reachable from your computer.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰.  I din't get you

Comment: It says `ETIMEDOUT ` so your node process was not able to reach the desired server and port, shell command `telnet` (both windows and *nix have it) can tell you if some port on some server is reachable, so you can know if ti's the network is bad and you can't reach the server, or the server is reachable but your code has some problem.

Comment: I am Trying to connect it for mlab